# Bukkit - Why does casting to Damageable work?

Tags: java, interface, minecraft, overloading, bukkit

From Bukkit 1.6.4 on there was another way to handle to players life, the life is stored as double from now on. To be compatible to older plugins the `Player.getHealth()` method is ambigious, there are:

```
@Deprecated
public int getHealth();
public double getHealth();
```

I was trying to use `Player.getHealth()` and ended up with an error. I searched for a solution, but things like `double d = (double) player.getHealth()` or `double d = new Double(player.getHealth());` still throw the error `The method getHealth() of Player is ambigious` (I am using Eclipse btw.). But after some search I also found this:

```
Damageable d = player; //because player is a Damageable
double health = d.getHealth();
//the method called is the "new one", which returns a double
```

I don't understand why this works, because I took a look at Damageable and the two ambigious methods are already defined in Damageable. The error described above should also occur here. Where am I wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post a link to the relevant javadoc. What I find lists just the double method.

Comment: I think you meant this:
http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Damageable.html#getHealth()
http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html
(The second one is the doc of Player, but the two methods are just listed in Damageable (first link))
But I think these can't help you with the problem.

Comment: Seems like it. Neither the javadocs nor the source code mentions this method, but looking at the .class file in craftbukkit.jar shows that it really is there. In fact all methods with `_INVALID_` prefix in the name seems to have lost that prefix. A quick search for ClassFileTransformer turned up nothing and I'm not good enough at this kind of compile time mutation of stuff to be able to figure this out.

Comment: As an aside my understanding of the java specification is that this is a compile time error. If this happens to be correct and bukkit uses some kind of black magic to work around that then I suspect the behaviour of calling that class method might not be well defined, and possibly vary from jvm to jvm.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in Minecraft 1.6.4 and up, the health is now stored in a float. Bukkit decided to use a double to protect against a future change from float to double. If you don't use `NMS` anywhere, use only [`bukkit`](http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/), and not `craftbukkit`, as this will make it so that you can just do `double d = player.getHealth();`. Otherwise if you need `craftbukkit`, you could put `bukkit` higher than `craftbukkit` in your build hierarchy.

`Damageable.getHealth()` is a method from Bukkit, so it is not deprecated, while `Player.getHealth()` is a method in CraftBukkit (CraftBukkit uses code mostly from the original Minecraft server, (called NMS), so It *IS* deprecated. Although if you were to remove `CraftBukkit` from your build path, or put `Bukkit` above it, then `Player.getHealth()` would work.

Bukkit deprecated the `.getHealth()` methods that use integers, although they still work, but they will be removed soon. So, at the moment, you need to use `double health = ((Damageable) player).getHealth();`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not exactly what I asked for. You put a good solution to that problem in your answer, but I asked why `Damageable.getHealth()` works, even though this method is ambigious.